# What is the idiomatic Java 8 way of handling a CompletableFuture that often cannot return a valid result?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, option-type, completable-future

Let's say we are calling a slow remote service to get a `String` response. To do this we call a method that looks like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> getSlowly(String param) {...}
```

In this scenario, we also know we know that the service will not return a useful response in 20% of the times we call it. So 20% of the times we call `getSlowly` we will get an exceptionally completed future with some wrapped exception. Meaning, we will end up in the `catch` block of the following call:

```
try {
    String response = getSlowly("some input").join();
    doSomething(response); // 80% succeed
catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.warn("Couldn't get response. Too bad."); // 20% fail
}
```

This call is not critical and our application can gracefully handle the missing response. However, we do want to use the response whenever we do manage to get one successfully.

Because we know that this failure will happen often, i.e. we do *expect* it, does it make sense to treat these 20% of calls as *exceptional*?

One way of not treating the 20% as exceptional would be to change the implementation of `getSlowly` to something like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<Optional<String>> getSlowly(String param) {...}
```

This looks unwieldy.

Is there an idiomatic way we should handle such flaky CompletableFutures? Should we consider it an exceptional state when a return value is missing, or should we instead return optionals (or similar custom objects)?

Comment: I think whether a state is considered exceptional or not should depend on whether it's part of normal business, rather than expected frequency. (Though obviously the two are not completely independent.)

Comment: Why not use [`thenAccept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-)? You could combine it with [`exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) to handle the problem cases - log and `return null` for example. I would avoid using `join` or `get` with a `CompleteableFuture` - they're designed to create an _asynchronous_ pipeline.

Comment: Since you are considering the failure worth being logged, it doesn’t seem to be an expected case.

Comment: @Holger As a separate question it probably is also worth considering who would ever read that log. Chances are that the answer is: nobody.

Comment: @biziclop I included the frequency (20%) just for illustration purposes. My main point was to say that it is expected that `getSlowly` will not return a value. I.e. it is not an a truly exceptional state.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The main point of the question is handling _expected_ cases when a CompletableFuture does not successfully return a value. The current CompletableFuture API forces us to treat these as exceptions. This is in contradiction with the usual Java wisdom of never using exceptions for handling cases that you do expect to happen.

Comment: @hvth Is this any different from a simple method call? If you had a simple method returning a `String`, and you wanted to handle that case, what would you do?

Comment: If it was a simple synchronous method call, I'd go for an `Optional`. But the `CompletableFuture` is in a sense also similar to an Optional. They are both monads that will either return a value or not (https://gist.github.com/ms-tg/7420496 , https://gist.github.com/lestard/e28fb8a340737ffd9623). So it just seems a bit superfluous to use both at the same time. I guess what I wanted to draw attention to is that the CompletableFuture API forces us to use exceptions to denote that there is no value in the monad, even though that state might not be exceptional at all.

Comment: @hvth, I hadn't noticed your last comment but you could maybe complete your future with a `null` or another dummy value. There is probably little value to put an `Optional` inside a `CompletableFuture` indeed.